# Storefront child theme not applying parent theme

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, themes

I've followed, word for word, the Storefront guide for creating a child theme: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/

I've got a new folder in my themes folder, added a blank functions.php and style.css containing:

```
/* 
Theme Name: Storefront Child 
Version: 1.0 
Description: Child theme for Storefront. 
Author: Me
Author URI: 
Template: storefront 
*/
```

Activating the child theme, on a completely fresh install of Storefront (with a logo and menu added), resets it completely, and doesn't seem to be inheriting anything. On the guide, it says:

`With Storefront, you do not need to enqueue any of the parent theme style files with PHP from the theme’s functions.php file or import these into the child themes style.css file as the main parent Storefront theme does this for you.`

And:

`With Storefront, a child theme only requires a blank functions.php file and a style.css file to get up and running.`

So I'm at a loss what to do.